# CSS hovering over image showing another with opacity

Tags: html, css, image, opacity

So what i first did was making image 1 have a low opacity and image 2 have no opacity, and what i want is making image 2 and 1 appear in full opacity when being hovered over image 1. But i don't know how to make them both appear so i hope someone knows if there's a better way of doing this or tell me how.``
**CSS:**

```
.img1 {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:-20px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
img:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
.img2{
        opacity: 0;
    position:fixed;
    right:50px;
    bottom:70px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <img src="img1.png" class="img1">
    <img src="img2.png" class="img2">
```

So what i want is when you hover over image 1 image 2 and 1 show in full opacity i hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`+`, Adjacent sibling combinator or `~`, General sibling combinator](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

```
.img1:hover ~ .img2 , .img1:hover {
     opacity: 1.0;
}
```

or

```
.img1:hover + .img2 , .img1:hover {
     opacity: 1.0;
}
```